# Applying Toggle Class to Image Element

Tags: html, css

I am building an Ionic app and I want to click on the image and change it with a different image. It is a toggle functionality.

I have the following class:

```
img{
&.default {
  background-image: url("img/726-star.png");
  &.activated{
    background-image: url("img/726-star-selected.png");
  }
}
```

And I apply the class as shown below:

```
<img class="default" style="width:38px;height:38px;margin-top:30px;"/>
```

But when I see in the Chrome Debugger tools I don't see the default class being applied. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: So, I am using DIV now instead of an image but I don't see the image displayed in the div:

```css
#favImage {
  &.default { 
    background-image: url("img/726-star.png"); 
  } 
  &.activated { 
    background-image: url("img/726-star-selected.png"); 
  } 
}
```

```html
<div id="favImage" class="default" style="width:38px;height:38px;margin-top:30px;"></div>
```

Comment: try `img{
&.default {
  background-image: url("img/726-star.png");
  }
&.activated{
    background-image: url("img/726-star-selected.png");
  }
}`

Comment: use `div` or `span` for it, not `img` tag

Comment: Please see the updated question with the edits.

Comment: see is any error in  the developer console network tab.. Check the image path also

Comment: Image path looks correct. no errors on the console!

Comment: use `background-size: cover` also

Comment: Generally, it's should work.. http://jsbin.com/deqate/edit?html,css,output. If it doesn't, please create a snippet or bin so we could help you to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all  i recommened you to sparate your style in the html to a css file. 
second if you are using img tag don't forget to insert src attribute to the img tag other wise the img won't show. 
to change the image by clicking on it i use JavaScript function that activated by write an attribute on the img tag "onclick" and call the JavaScript function.
the function take  image id into a variable and with the use of a match  method check if the image src contains string "726-star-not" if its not the image src changes to "726-star-selected" and vice versa.

[to learn more about the match method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)

```js
function myFunction() {
     
    var image = document.getElementById('favImage');
    
    if (image.src.match("726-star-not")) {
        image.src = "img/726-star-selected.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "img/726-star-not.png";
    }

}
```

```css
#favImage{
    width:38px;
    height:38px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        <script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
              
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="favImage" src="img/726-star-not.png" onclick="myFunction()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was wondering if all of this can be done by CSS only without having to write any JS code.